# Angular ui-router not working in Cordova Ripple iOS and Android Devices

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-2015, angular-ui-router

I have a bootstrap/angular js ui-router app that is created in windows visual studio on a windows tablet. Originally the need was to have the app for Windows users, now its needed for all devices.

After the app was created for browser, I was able to import it into visual studio for cordova. I got everything working testing in Windowsx64 - local machine settings. I tried plugging my iphone to tablet to test the iOS version of the app but I never got that working. So I tried testing with the Ripple simulator that Visual Studio comes with. The simple start page and any other apps would work great from device to device, but just this specific app ui-router and styles do not transfer over and do not show up on iOS and Android. No errors logs show up when in iOS or Android mode.

the code behind the app:
index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="routerApp">
<head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <!-- STYLE SHEETS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Clinical Cases Program</title>
</head>
<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="landing">Clinical Cases App</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <h1>The device is running</h1>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```js
routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
  // HOME VIEWS =================================
         .state('landing', {
             url: '/home',
             templateUrl: 'templates/partial-landing.html'
         })

        // FILTERS VIEWS ========================================
        .state('filters', {
            url: '/filters',
            templateUrl: 'templates/partial-filters.html',
            controller: 'FilterToggleController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        // CASES VIEWS =================================
        .state('cases', {
            url: '/cases',
            templateUrl: 'templates/partial-cases.html',
            controller: 'CasesController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });

});

//"myApp" is the your module
routerApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|ms-appx-web|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
}]);
```

Is there a specific folder in Visual Studio or Cordova that overwrites these style/script? Is there something wrong with Ripple simulators?

Attached are screenshots of the original windows app and other iOS and Android Ripple.

Windows x64 - local machine
[image]
[image]

Android - Ripple-Nexus(Galaxy)
[image]

Android Ripple - Nexus 7 (tablet)
[image]

iOS - Ripple iphone 5
[image]

iOS - Ripple ipad 3
[image]

Comment: Could you share some of your code? Especially the config of the UI-router might be interesting...

Comment: I added my index page and app.js code

Comment: Does your source code look the same in the DOM explorer? (as in, do you still see the button element in the source code of that page?) It may be because the screen size is smaller that the button is actually out of view.

Comment: Linda DOM explorer does not display the button, nor ui-view. The buttons dont also work for ui-sref. UI router does not work on the Ripple simulator for me. All other Angular js does including the ng-src.